# Blank value is displayed in combo box in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have following combobox contexts :-

```
 <select name="destination" id="destination" style="width: 125px;"
         onchange="onChangeDestination(this.value,'0');">
     <option value="2" selected>2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

Now I am selecting a value as "2" and submitting the form. Next time when I come to the same page I set values in combobox dynamically.

So instead of showing the value as "2" It showing me blank field having no value in IE.When I check the values, it shows me both ("2" and "3"). Once I again select any value then blank field disappears.
Again same issue comes when I refresh the page.

[image: Please find image for reference]

Comment: what `onChangeDestination` does?

Comment: Show the JavaScript for how you set the value dynamically.

Comment: onChangeDestination will simply get the value of the combo box and generates text fields accordingly. for example, if value is 2 then 2 text fields are displayed and value is 3 then 3 text fields are diaplayed

Comment: So show the code for the bit that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried but I can always see it (using IE9 here):

**Live** [example at JsBin](http://jsbin.com/awoluh/2/edit)

But now that you posted an image, please let us know what is your `DOCTYPE`...

I'm sure that you are using an old one and you need to specify:

```
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
```

instead of what you have.

And by the way... you should have a "Please select" option as if you don't run on DOM ready the `onChange` code how would you want the user to see 2 textfields without choosing `3` and then back `2` ...

an `<option value="-1" selected="selected">Please select</option>` would do the trick where in the javascript method, `if ( parseInt(a, 10) == -1 ) return;` will avoid any textboxed creation.

Comment: Thanks balexandre !!! Actually when loading the page, two text fields are displayed which means that destination combo has the value "2".Just it is not showing that value.Itried selected="selected" but yet not getting any result.

Comment: what IE version are you testing with? is this plain HTML or any dynamic language and that dropdown is generated on the fly?

Comment: IE 6+. Plain HTML has shown here but the values in the combo are filled dynamically.

Comment: **Microsoft no longer supports IE6**, so you shouldn't as well! - Do you have any problem when rendering the **JSBin example** that I posted? if you are adding values dynamically, you can't use `selected="selected"` as that's only there when the dropdown is constructed, you need to select the value programmatically as well using, for example: `$("#destination").val("3");`